# Set and change image every 5s - where to put setInterval in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I set `main-image` and change it every 5 second in loop? Where is the best place to put `setInterval` function?

```
<template>
<div class="main-image">
    <img src="...">
</div>
<div class="image-list>
   <div v-for="img in images" class="item"><img src="img.image"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Images',
  data () {
    return {
      images: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  created () {
    this.images = [
       {
          id: '23',
          image: 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
       },
       {
          id: '32',
          image: 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
       },
       {
          id: '45',
          image: 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
       },
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to bind the main image src to a data object like below:]. Your created function will run the `setInterval` function

```
<template>
<div class="main-image">
    <img :src="mainImageSrc">
</div>
<div class="image-list>
   <div v-for="img in images" class="item"><img src="img.image"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Images',
  data () {
    return {
      images: [],
      mainImageSrc: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  created () {
    let self = this
    this.images = [
       {
          id: '23',
          image: 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
       },
       {
          id: '32',
          image: 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
       },
       {
          id: '45',
          image: 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
       },
    ]

    setInterval(function(){ 
        self.mainImageSrc = self.images[Math.floor(Math.random()*self.images.length)].image;
    }, 5000);

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should use an arrow function